# Uneven current distribution in center-tap transformer secondary winding of LLC resonant converter at low load

Tags: power-supply, rectifier, resonant-converter

I'm trying to design an 24V 50W LLC resonant converter with a resonance frequency of 250kHz.
I've run into an issue with the center-tapped transformer that i can't quite find a reason for though.

For some reason one half-period (When M1 is open) barely transfers any current from the primary side to the secondary side at light loads. At heavy loads this seems to be much less of an issue.

If anyone can explain what's going on, or link some articles explaining it, i'd be very grateful.

I have attached any relevant waveforms i could think of, but the main ones are the 2 diode currents at the bottom (I(D1) & I(D2)). Also V6 is supposed to be a start-up pulse that will turn off after a while, but right now it's just a DC source for the gate-driver.

[image]
The circuit
[image: Waveforms at light load]
Waveforms at light load(100Ohms)

[image]
Waveforms at heavier load(10Ohms) - here there's an issue of D1 conducting before D2 is at 0A which also shouldn't happen as far as i know. This issue also seems to disappear at even heavier loads, which is more than this power supply is supposed to deliver though.

[image: Ideal waveforms at resonance]

Ideal waveforms at resonance
(from: https://powersimtech.com/drive/uploads/2018/04/Designing-LLC-resonant-converter-TI-slup263.pdf)

Any help or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why wouldn't you expect barely any current on light loads?

Comment: It's not that i expect a lot of current. My issue is that it's not evenly distributed across the two secondary windings, even though they, as far as i know, should carry the same amount.

Comment: Why should they carry the same current (at the same time)?

Comment: They shouldn't carry the same current at the same time. 
They should however carry an equal amount of current at opposite half-periods. I was expecting the light load waveforms to look more like the heavier load waveforms where D1 and D2 conducts almost the same amount of current.
I've added a picture to the top post to with the ideal waveforms, which i can achieve when i increase the load further above 50W.

Comment: OK, I think I see what you mean - the inductor L4 would have to reverse its current within one switching cycle if you were to see equal currents in both secondary diodes. This just won't happen on a light load. Because of that there will be an imbalance.